# How to return a query from an anonymous function and pass it to a forward pipe

Tags: f#

I have a query that is then forward piped to an anonymous function.  I would like this function to utilize the query and then forward pipe it to the next function.  Not sure if this possible as I am having trouble accomplishing this.

so far I have this:

```
// find file for deletion
let findFileToDelete id = 

    // query
    query{
        for row in db.Uploads do
        where (row.Id = id)
        select row
        exactlyOneOrDefault
    } 
    |> (fun q -> File.Delete(q.FilePath))
```

But I would like to continue on with something like this:

```
// find file for deletion
let findFileToDelete id = 

    // query
    query{
        for row in db.Uploads do
        where (row.Id = id)
        select row
        exactlyOneOrDefault
    } 
    |> (fun q -> File.Delete(q.FilePath)) q // forward pipe the query
    |> deleteRowFrom db.Uploads q

    // update the database
    saveToDb()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark pointed out, pipelining is generally used for a series of *transformations*. Your code performs a series of *actions*. I recommend writing it like this:

```
// find file for deletion
let findFileToDelete id = 

    let row = 
        query {
            for row in db.Uploads do
            where (row.Id = id)
            exactlyOneOrDefault
        } 

    File.Delete row.FilePath
    deleteRowFrom db.Uploads row

    // update the database
    saveToDb()
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for ending the query with Seq.head?

Comment: So you can deal with a single row instead of an `IQueryable`. I think that makes your intent clearer.

Comment: `exactlyOneOrDefault` already returns a single row, not a sequence. The code with `Seq.head` doesn't compile.

Comment: @Tarmil: You're right. Thanks. It's fixed. Also removed `select` since it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

F# has significant whitespace, and the most normal way of separating multiple statements is by separating them with a newline, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
let findFileToDelete id = 

    // query
    query{
        for row in db.Uploads do
        where (row.Id = id)
        select row
        exactlyOneOrDefault
    } 
    |> (fun q ->
        File.Delete(q.FilePath)
        q) // forward pipe the query
    |> deleteRowFrom db.Uploads

    // update the database
    saveToDb()
```

However, I generally wouldn't recommend doing something like this, as it introduces **side-effects** into the middle of a query. This is likely to make your code more difficult to reason about.

Instead, I would recommend assigning the query to a value with a `let` binding, and then pass it to [`Seq.iter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340396.aspx) to do all the operations with side effects, and reuse it in a query if you need to do that.

Comment: So are you suggesting that instead of using the forward pipe for this operation I should but the query in its own value/variable?

Comment: You can also separate statements with a semicolon, so you can do it as a one-liner: `(fun q -> File.Delete(q.FilePath); q)`.  I agree that you don't want to do this a lot but I was just using it today to get quick-and-dirty progress reports from a script that was reading a set of very large files, thus: `|> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (if i % 100000 = 0 then Console.WriteLine("Line {0,10:N0}", i)); x)`